# HTML5 Cache Spring Project Ajax calls issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, spring

I have a spring mvc project,

i want offline functionality for the pages being rendered
so
i have a manifest file which includes the jsps ,css,js ,images etc.

The issue i am facing is

Once i open the web page and the cache is downloaded to the browser and i am still online the ajax calls stop working ,(when offline i dont need ajax calls to work)

this is the error shown in console

```
GET http://localhost:8080/test/rest/store/1 net::ERR_FAILED
m.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
storeDetails @ index.jsp:143
onclick @ index.jsp:191
jquery.min.js:4 
net::ERR_FAILED(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4m.access @ jquery.min.js:3m.each.m.fn.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6m.fn.extend.on.d @ jquery.min.js:3a.support.transition.a.event.special.bsTransitionEnd.handle @ bootstrap.min.js:6m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3m.event.trigger @ jquery.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:3m.extend.each @ jquery.min.js:2m.fn.m.each @ jquery.min.js:2m.fn.extend.trigger @ jquery.min.js:3a.fn.emulateTransitionEnd.e @ bootstrap.min.js:6
```

Comment: add timestamp param in url,like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259050/html5-cache-spring-project-ajax-calls-issue?tms=1436238644460

Comment: @flowerszhong it causes the ajax call to fail,the controller wont recognize this extra parameter in the url right?

Comment: Unbound HTTP parameters are ignored by Spring controllers. However, it's no clear why you think the problem you're getting is related to cache at all. You didn't explain what the intended behaviour is. If you want your app that uses AJAX to work in offline by using browser's cache you may find it impossible to implement reliably across multiple browsers just by relying on cache expiration.

Comment: as i mentioned above the offline part works great , the problem is once cache is downloaded and im still online ajax calls dont work, i remove the cache meta tag and vola it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
NETWORK
*
```

to my cache file got the ajax calls working again. !

Answer (score -1):

hard code when send a ajax request,like:

```
if(isLocalENV){
 jQuery.ajax({
   url:url,
   data:{tms:+new Date(),param1:value1},
   ...
  })};
```